# Crashlytics issue in Video player

Tags: flutter, dart, video, video-player

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: 
PlatformException
(
    VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.k: 
    MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, 
    index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640020, -1, null, 
    [1080, 1080, 25.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null 
)
at FirebaseCrashlytics.recordError(firebase_crashlytics.dart:119)
at main.<fn>(main.dart:136)
```

Comment: Try to ask an actual **programming question** about an issue in your project. Try to provide technical details (the **what**, **where**, **how** and **why**) about your code. Right now it's not obvious what you want to achieve...

Comment: This issue is carshlytics issue, not a code issue. If I have a solution I can't post the question here